# printer ink expense and not enough satisfaction

Tags: printer

I have two printers one of which is a Cannon IP2700.  Since I seem to have printing issues that  make the copy not look very good, and my non-computer tech mentality (aka: husband) has issues with my in-adept abilities to correct this issue, my question is if I replace the color cartridge with a black cartridge what damage could this cause???  I want one of my printers to be black only without the additional expense of constantly replacing color cartridges and I also am going to try using refill kits instead of the pricey brand cartridge.  What is your opinion of doing this?  the other printer is a Epson Stylus CX6000 that is an "all in one" unit that works fairly well and I would leave that as is.

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply you can't put a black cartridge into a colour cartridge slot - they are physically different.Just tell the printer to print in black and white/greyscale, and just not replace the colour carts when empty.

On the other hand, canon printers in my experience are rather forgiving of refilling (the older ones just checked the ink level. The newer ones will claim ink is low, and cheerfully print anyway), and while they'll complain, print fine with either a refilled or empty printer cart. I've not had any major issues with refills so far, but YMMV.